# Identifying most frequent fractional numbers in vector

Tags: r

I have a vector that contains fractional numbers:

```
a<-c(0.5,0.5,0.3,0.5,0.2)
```

I would like to determine the most frequent (i.e. majority) number in the vector and return that number.

`table(a)` doesn't work because it will return the whole table. I want it to return only `0.5`.

In case of ties I would like to choose randomly.

I have a function that does this for integers:

```
function(x){ 
    a<-tabulate(x,nbins=max(x)); b<-which(a==max(a))
if (length(b)>1) {a<-sample(b,1)} else{b}
}
```

However, this won't work for fractions.

Can someone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
names(which.max(table(a)))
```

If you want the numeric one as in your case, then coerce it to numeric

```
as.numeric(names(which.max(table(a))))
```

To randomize the tie case, you can add randomize the table

```
as.numeric(names(which.max(sample(table(a))))) #note this works only if length(unique(a)) > 1
```

Comment: great this will work. the only thing is the case of ties. I would like to choose randomly then. Imagine a<-c(0.5,0.5,0.6,0.6) this code will always return 0.5, but I want it to choose randomly between 0.5 and 0.6.

Comment: This returns "0.5", not 0.5.

Comment: also if there's only a<-c(0.5,0.5,0.5) this code will return numeric(0)